# Understanding rotation and calculating the top left point in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, rotation, kineticjs

I am working on a page where I can view images.  I want to create a rotation tool.  I've done that, but, it's not working consistently.  When I set up the centre point to rotate by, the image jumps slightly, and it gets worse each time.  I was experimenting, and, I have code to add a wedge to the top left corner of my top level group ( so, at 0,0 ).  If I rotate the image by 45 degrees and drag it so that half of it is off the left edge of my canvas, then I call getAbsolutePosition on the wedge and on the group, I get these values:

layer.getAbsolutePosition()
Object {x: 104.66479545850302, y: 279.2748571151325}
wedge.getAbsolutePosition()
Object {x: 180.2684127179338, y: -73.48773356791764}

I think this means my y position is actually the bottom of the image, which is off screen.

What I want to do, is calculate the absolute position of the middle of my image, when the mouse moves over it, regardless of it's rotation.  I have some code that works out points with rotation, which seems like it works at first, almost, but it just gets more and more broken the more I use the tool.  I feel like there's something about how Kinetic is tracking these things and what it's reporting, that I am missing.  Any hints would be most appreciated.  Tutorials I can read are even better ( yes, I've read everything linked from the KineticJS site and searched the web ).

In a nutshell, the question is, if I have an image inside a group, and it's rotated, how do I work out the centre point of the image, taking the rotation in to account, and how do I set the offset so it will rotate from that point, and stay in the same place ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered about KinetiJS:

- rotation is easy
- dragging is easy
- dragging+rotation is difficult

**After you drag your image you must reset its rotation point (offsetX/offsetY).**

KineticJS makes dragging+rotation more difficult than it has to be.

Resetting the offset points of your image will cause KineticJS to automatically move your image (Noooo!!).

That's what's causing your jumping.

**The solution to the "jumping" problem:**

When you reset the image's rotation point (offsetX/OffsetY) you must also reset the image's X/Y position.

This code resets both XY and Offsets for an image after dragging:

A Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/m9Nw7/

```
// calc new position and offset

var pos=rect.getPosition();
var size=rect.getSize();
var offset=rect.getOffset();
var newX=pos.x-offset.x+size.width/2;
var newY=pos.y-offset.y+size.height/2;

// reset both position and offset

rect.setPosition([newX,newY]);
rect.setOffset(size.width/2,size.height/2);
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was my second attempt to ask for help on this issue, the first post was a lot longer and included code.  I am actually doing something similar to this  already, but when I do it, my image jumps a little, and jumps a lot after subsequent rotations.  I have a group within a group, does that matter ? Is setting the offset on the top level group enough ? Basically, the first time I move the mouse over the image, it is off by a few pixels.  The next time I move over the image ( so it recalculates ), it is wrong, and gets more wrong.  This happens if I rotate the image or not.

Comment: Yes, you must first reset the group position and offset relative to the stage. Then you must next reset the image position and offset relative to the group.

Comment: Awesome, I woke up this morning thinking that may be the issue, I guess you've confirmed it, that gives me a real path forward, so thanks again

Comment: OK, I can't post the code I wrote to solve this in the end, but it's based on your code, but setPosition requires an object with an X and Y, and I needed to use setPositionX and setPositionY.  One final question - the image still jumps slightly the first time the mouse goes over, but it doesn't after that.  Any suggestions why ?  Thanks again.

Comment: What I have to change if I want to move rotator(small purple circle) controller in your example?

Comment: @Razib The purple rotator circle is draggable...just drag it! ;-)